# AWS Athena json_extract query from string field returns empty values

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have in Athena json string:

{"recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee":0,"recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.assistant":1}

I need get result: trainee=0

I make a query:

```sql
select 
     json_extract(
     '{"recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee":0,"recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.assistant":1}', 
     '$.recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee')
```

And I have a empty result. I think the problem is mit dots. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'$.recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee'` represents path to property of deeply nested object, something like the following:

```json
{
   "recurrent_jobs":{
      "new_page":{
         "career_level":{
            "trainee":0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You need to escape the property name with dots - `'$["recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee"]'`:

```sql
select json_extract(
    '{
        "recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee":0,
        "recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.assistant":1
    }',
    '$["recurrent_jobs.new_page.career_level.trainee"]');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 0 |